# JQuery roundabout - getting ID of selected <lI> each time the roundabout finishes moving

Tags: jquery, syntax

I'm using the JQ roundabout plugin from:

http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/

Have it set up and working - but struggling to get one of the hookable events to work.
There's not really a syntax example on any of the demos so it may just be my stupidity.

I'm initiating the roundabout as follows:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#productRoundel').roundabout(
        {
            shape: 'tearDrop',
            focusBearing: '5.0'
        });

    $("#productRoundel").roundabout.animationEnd(function() {

        alert("hello");

    }); 

});
</script>
```

Can anyone give me a pointer on the correct syntax to get an event triggering once the animation has completed so that I can then get the ID of the current slide?

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have not tested or used this plugin, but you should be able to bind to the event to listen for it.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#productRoundel').roundabout(
        {
            shape: 'tearDrop',
            focusBearing: '5.0'
        });

    $("#productRoundel").bind( 'animationEnd', function() {

        alert("hello");

    }); 

});
```

Comment: Thank you Kory. For some reason the bind solution totally escaped me - must have been having a bad day! This works perfectly.