# Javascript: how to record click image to json?

Tags: javascript, onclick, image

My form needs to have multiple images listed.  The user will need ability to click an image to pick their swatch.  How do you pass the name of the image to the script below?

I understand how a dropdown menu gives choices and the "***select***" part has an "id"... the "***option***" has a value.  But how does it work with images?  Is there a way to give each one a unique label, but somehow let the script know they're all options of the same group?

```
<img src="myimage_one.jpg">
<img src="myimage_two.jpg">
<img src="myimage_three.jpg">
```

Do they all need to share the same identity like a "***radio***" element does and then the one you pick becomes the ID that gets sent through my script?

Below is my script which gets triggered for every dropdown selection, every input field filled out, and should be for every "onclick" that happens. So basically, the "***select***" and "***input***" elements are firing based on "doCalc();" part of the script below.

Reason for script is to instantly auto-calculate the total which each selection and then it displays into a specific id placeholder.

Lastly, doesn't the value needs to be somehow attached to myimage_str as you'll see in the script below?

var myimageX = $('#myimage_str').val();

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function doCalc(){
                var roomX = $('#room_str').val();
                var otherroomX = $('#other_room').val();
                var myimageX = $('#myimage_str').val();                 
                var heightX = $('#height_str').val();
                var heightfracX = $('#heightfrac_str').val();
                var widthX = $('#width_str').val();
                var widthfracX = $('#widthfrac_str').val();
                var prodid = $('#prodid').val();
                var qtyX = $('#qty_str').val();

                $.post('db_query.php',
                {qtyX:qtyX, roomX:roomX, otherroomX:otherroomX, myimageX:myimageX, heightX:heightX, heightfracX:heightfracX, widthX:widthX, widthfracX:widthfracX, prodid:prodid}, 
                function(data) {
                    data = $.parseJSON(data);
                    $('#width-placeholder').html(data.width);
                    $('#widthfrac-placeholder').html(data.widthfrac);
                    $('#height-placeholder').html(data.height);
                    $('#heightfrac-placeholder').html(data.heightfrac);
                    $('#realtime-price').html(data.totalprice);
                    $('#realtime-qty').html(data.qty);
                    $('#unitprice').html(data.unitprice);
                    $('#roomname').html(data.roomname);
                    $('#other_room-placeholder').html(data.otherroom);
                    $('#myimage-placeholder').html(data.myimage);
                    // ...
                });
                return false;
                };
        </script>
```

EDIT:  Here is code added per your suggestion.  It's still not working.  When I click the image, nothing happens.  I tried using the attr for "alt" tag and give the image name in that.  var colorX = $('.ColorSelection').attr('alt');

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
                $('.ColorChoice').click(function(){
                    $('.ColorChoice').removeClass('ColorSelection');
                    $(this).addClass('ColorSelection'); 
                    doCalc()
                });
                function doCalc(){
                var roomX = $('#room_str').val();
                var otherroomX = $('#other_room').val();
                var colorX = $('.ColorSelection').attr('alt');  
//.....
```

Here are a couple of the images...

```
<ul class="swatches">
  <li><div id="swatch"><img src="100_bright_white.jpg" alt="100_bright_white" class="ColorChoice"></div></li>
  <li><div id="swatch"><img src="101_pure_white.jpg" alt="101_pure_white" class="ColorChoice"></div></li>
  <li><div id="swatch"><img src="102_bone.jpg" alt="102_bone" class="ColorChoice">
//...</div></li>
```

Comment: I've found this way of grabbing the src and trimming it down to the file name.       var src = $('#10').prop('src');
     var colorname = src.replace(/^.*\/|\.jpg$/g, '');
     var colorX = colorname;  This is great but I do not know how to make it so the #10 (which is the ID of a particular image which I typed manually) to become dynamic based on click.  I've tried all the solutions suggested but with no success.

Answer (score 1):

You could class all of the images the same, and then when you click on the image it gets a clicked class. Then get the data in your doCalc function. Something like the following might work

For the sake of this example your images are all classed as .imgChoice and the one you want is .imgSelection

```
$('.imgChoice').click(function(){
    $('.imgChoice').removeClass('imgSelection');
    $(this).addClass('imgSelection');    
});
```

And then to get the value

```
var myimageX = $('.imgSelection').attr('src');
```

That will assign the source value/file name to the variable myimageX. If that's not quite what you're looking for let me know.

Comment: will the .click(function) be a problem since I need it to be clicked and trigger the doCalc function?  When the image is clicked it has to make the doCalc happen immediately.  Both can happen at the same time?

Comment: You could add the doCalc function to execute directly after the lick function, that would work. You would do that by adding doCalc at the end of the click function, so yes, they can happen at the same time. The finished product would be

    `$('.imgChoice').click(function(){
        $('.imgChoice').removeClass('imgSelection');
        $(this).addClass('imgSelection');  
        doCalc()
   });`

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working.  I'll paste some of my code above.  Thank you!

Comment: Part of the problem may be that you are using the id Swatch multiple times. ID's are only supposed to be used once per page. I would try removing the ID from the swatches, perhaps move it to a class? You can use multiple classes if you separate them with a space like this 

`class="classone classtwo classthree ect"`

Comment: does it make any difference that those images are on a "carousel" which also has it's own CSS.  It's called "roundabout" which is a javascript that causes the images to rotate with each click.  http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout .  The one "in focus" is, of course, the front image which has it's own styling controlled by the script.  Here is the CSS they're using on those images.     .roundabout-moveable-item {
      height: 140px;
      width: 140px;
      cursor: pointer;
      border: 0px solid #999;
   }
   .roundabout-in-focus {
      cursor: auto;
   border: 2px solid #f48153;
   }

Comment: Do you have the click function in a document ready/load function? If not give that a shot.

Comment: Thank you for trying but I may have to give up.  I am finding out on other forums that the image effect i'm using "roundabout.js" might be altering the class and conflicting with these efforts.  I see something similar on this forum post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101609/jquery-roundabout-getting-id-of-selected-li-each-time-the-roundabout-finishe  It has to do with when the animation ends and when the image is in focus... and something about binding a click when it's the image in focus.  Thank you again for trying.

Answer (score 0):

In your form, put a hidden field to hold the value of the src attribute of the image selected by the user. Then, in your script (I'm assuming you're using jQuery):

```
$("img").click(function() {
    $("#myimage_str").val($(this).attr("src"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to accomplish this. One would be to wrap your images in a div that you can identify the block of images.

```
<div id="myimage_str">
  <img src="myimage_one.jpg">
  <img src="myimage_two.jpg">
  <img src="myimage_three.jpg">
</div>
```

Then add the following javascript (I'm assuming your using jQuery):

```
$('#myimage_str').click(function() {
   $('#myimage_str img').removeClass('selected');
   $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

And in your 'doCalc' method you can simply write:

```
var myimageX = $('#myimage_str img.selected').attr('src');
```

Alternatively, you could put a common class name to identify the block of images. But I think wrapping it makes it easier to see the logical block of images (and will likely be the case for styling on UI).

Comment: I will definitely try this method if I can't get the above to work.  I'm fairly new here and wanted to try what I felt that I understood, but also in order as they answered.  Is that how it's supposed to be done here?

Comment: It's common for several answers to be posted around the same time. The main thing is to mark the answer as the 'answer' that best suited your question and that answered your question. Think about people years from now with the same question and which answer you would like them to consider (the one that helped you solve the problem). Upvotes will move the most appropriate answer around with time anyway.